# PrestoDb Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection

Tags: emr, amazon-emr, presto

I am using Presto version 0.152.3 over AWS EMR version 5.2 and I have recently encountered this error couple of times:

`Query 20180504_144719_00005_abcde failed: Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`
when running a query involving join over two tables. Surprisingly, the query runs fine on another cluster with the same configuration.

I tried looking up online but couldn't find something relevant. I also tried

```
sudo restart presto-server
```

but it didn't solve it. Has anyone seen/solved this issue before?

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Presto 0.152.3 was released Sep 27, 2016.  Please upgrade to the newest release 0.200

Comment: Can you try latest EMR AMI release 5.13.0 which comes with Presto 0.194?

Comment: @annunarcist  thats what i tried, but was curious where this error all of a sudden is coming from so i could understand things better

Comment: Do you have the complete error stack trace you can post? Are you using any SSL/TLS settings on Presto?